# How do I fit a cumulative Gaussian distribution in R?

Tags: r, distributions, fitting, cumulative-distribution-function, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a cumulative Gaussian distribution function to my data, but I'm not sure how to do this. From what I understand, the fitting process tries to find the mean and standard deviation of the cumulative Gaussian that makes the function best fit my data, right? So I need a way of fitting the CDF while providing initial parameters for the fitting process. My data looks like this

```
     x       p
1   0.6    0.431
2   0.7    0.479
3   0.8    0.515
4   0.9    0.494
5   1      0.535
6   1.1    0.545
7   1.2    0.538
8   1.3    0.587
9   1.4    0.629
```

Where `p` is the average confidence of participants for that $x_i$

I tried using `glm()` but I don't fully understand `glm()` or its output, so I don't know if I accomplished what I wanted.

```
fit <- glm(p ~ x, family = binomial(link=probit), data=dataset)
```

One example of something in `glm()` I don't understand is the fitted values:

```
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8            9 
0.4470200681 0.4672569250 0.4875787887 0.5079329624 0.5282664971 0.5485266046 0.5686610686 0.5886186480 0.6083494673
```

And another thing, how can I get the mean and standard deviation of my fitted function from the output of `glm()`? Any help would be much appreciated, I'm very new to R and statistics.

Comment: Because your values of "p" do not sum to 100%, they cannot possibly be chances corresponding to the $x_i$.  What are they really?  Would they perhaps correspond to chances of the intervals $(-\infty, x_i]$ for the data $x_i$? If so, how were they computed or estimated?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I don't know why I wrote that. p comes from data that relates to a person's level of confidence in their response. It goes from 1 to 5, and I converted them to percentages (1->10%,2->30%,3->50%, etc) and averaged them for each value of x. So you can consider p to be the person's confidence at that value of x (where 1 would be 100% confident).

Comment: You may be better off analysing the original response variable going from 1 to 5 using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression

Comment: Thank you for that resource. I'm trying to implement a model described by someone else, and it requires that I use the cumulative normal distribution. So I have to find some way to map the 1-5 scale to something usable in the cumulative Gaussian

Comment: Can you provide better description/reference of 'the model of this someone else' that you are using. Is it right? We can not answer your question without knowing what (and why!) you are doing this fit....

Comment: ... To me it seems like this binomial probit model might be performed on the *counts* in the responses 1 to 5, ie the y variable is a table of counts and the x variable is a number from 1 to 5. Or at least your current fit does make little sense. How does the variable $p$ relate to something like counts (which is the usual object/variable for which you apply a binomial family)? ...

Comment: The model is described in a paper: "A quantitative confidence signal detection model: 1. Fitting psychometric functions". I don't know if it is right; that's what I'm trying to determine by implementing the model. It fits a psychometric function as a cumulative Gaussian in the traditional way (using participants' yes/no response rate). Then it fits another cumulative Gaussian with the participants' confidence in their responses. It then re-fits the "confidence gaussian" while changing parameters to maximize an equation that I don't have space to explain. It's described in a char in the paper

Comment: ... about your fitted values. This seems to be because your variable `x` is treated as a categorical variable. Thus the model predicts a mean for each level. If you were expecting an intercept and a slope (instead of nine values) then you should have defines `x` as a continuous variable.

Comment: @supercoolusername123123 can you provide a link to the paper in your question. also better describe your data. are the nine x and p values your raw data or are you leaving some things behind?

Comment: https://www.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/jn.00318.2015
steps are described at the end of the paper in a flowchart

Comment: I have been reading the article only until figure 1. and scanned more quickly the rest of the article. It seems to be about a binary decision instead of a multiple choice / Likert scale. Does it treat multiple responses later on? There are many different ways to extend the problem for your case and you might expect some interesting answers, but could you please change your question making it more clear. Your problem seems to be much more about getting the correct model rather than a question about how to apply glm functions in R.

Comment: Could you provide a data table with the 45 values for the counts? (the number of times 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 had been selected for each of the 9 stimuli) Do you have repeated measures? (asking the same subject multiple questions)

Comment: I agree it seems to be about a binary decision. In their experiments, the participants make a binary choice and then provide a confidence rating on a scale from 1-100 (increments of 1). They don't really explain anything about treating multiple responses. It just says that they model the confidence ratings as a cumulative Gaussian. 

It is repeated measures. I'm not sure what you are referring to with the 45 values. Each participant has a different number of responses since we only look at trials where they reply with "yes". What is the best way to provide the data table?

Comment: For each of the nine x values you can report the number of people that answered 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. (which gives 45 numbers). Then you can fit a model for these counts which will be a 1 parameter for the dispersion of the perceived stimuli (the Gaussian distribution) and 4 parameters for decision boundaries. If you have sufficient counts then you can fit this using a minimization of the chi-squared statistic. (possibly you could do this with the simpler 'standard' glm as well, by coding your data as 4 binary decisions or making the decision a sum of 5 coin flips instead of a binary decision)....

Comment: .... the repeated measures makes it a bit tricky though. You could improve by introducing using some random effects (e.g. for the dispersion of the stimulus).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm totally new to statistics and R so I don't fully understand your last comment, or most of this stuff really. I will do more reading, I suppose. I'm afraid that this comment section is getting too long and I will be reprimanded. Thank you again for helping me.